# Best place to work together on a python project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, code-sharing

What is the best place to work with someone else on a python project and be able to edit the same code live (kind of like what you can do when you share a google document). Is there a way to work tighter with someone in pycharm?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true).

**Features:**

- essentially it's a jupyter notebook on google drive
- collaboratory programming
- many libraries come preinstalled (tensorflow, numpy, matplotlib, etc ...)
- runs on a vm (gpu and tpu available)
- can integrate with google drive
- completely free!